# Outlook web app displays both mobile and desktop versions of responsive email

Tags: responsive-design, html-email, outlook-web-app

Can someone please help?

I have created responsive email with desktop and mobile versions of code. It works fine in every mail client except in Outlook Web app that displays both versions.

I had the same problem with Outlook 2010, but I fixed it by wrapping mobile content in contidional mso comment:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: this is actually a pretty big issue with outlook.com, so this is not off topic. He would have had to have posted his entire code, which would have ended up being a debugging nightmare for potential answerers. Please open, I can post a solution.

Comment: Is there a way to explain to admins that its not ff topic, and what is the procedure for reopening the question? Anyone, please...

Comment: @ZephyrusDigital Can you please post a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Woo!

Anyway, I'm sure your email is set up with some `display:none` / `overflow:hidden` css on the div that wraps around your tables for the mobile version, but outlook.com doesn't always play nice.

I think outlook.com's finicky preprocessor is to blame.

What I've found to rectify this is to add a `.mobileonly{display:none;}` to your style tag, then add `class="mobileonly"` to any problem elements that keep popping up on tests. Most often you just need to do the higher up container tables.

If that doesn't work throw your html into a jsfiddle and I'll look further into it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, ZephyrusDigital. Unfortunately that solution works for Outlook mail, but not for Outlook Web App. Unfortunately, due to clients insisting I cannot provide you with jsfiddle, but trust me I have tried every solution available.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, didn't realize they were different. Don't have an office365 account and it's not on Litmus so I can't test. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same nightmare and tried everything in the book. Eventually I found a solution.

Set the containing column height to 0 - the desktop and mobile image each need their own class. The mobile image should have inline width & height also set to 0. Then in your desktop query... display:none, width and height set to 0 for mobile image.

Then in your responsive query you can force the height and width of the resp image and use display block. Try this it worked for me...even in Outlook 2003!